# How can I deploy web app on Tomcat from running app

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

I would like to develop updater app. Lets say I've got:
- Running Tomcat
- Running Updater App on the Tomcat
- Running old version of the app on the same Tomcat

I would like to
- Stop old app
- Undeploy old app
- Deploy new version of app (lets assume that I've got new app war file somewere in Updater app resourcess.

Is it possible to do such remote deployment on Tomcat from another app at all?

Comment: what procedure do you follow for deployment?
Do you use tomcat manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy a project to your Tomcat Server from another app you need to:

Add a library into your project “catalina-ant.jar” from the folder: {TOMCAT_PATH}\lib
And in your project to deploy a war file you need to only do:

```
org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask task = new org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask();
task.setUrl("http://localhost:8084/manager");
task.setUsername("managerLogin");
task.setPassword("managerPassword");
task.setPath("/UrlToYourDeploadingProject");
task.setWar(new File("c:/Project.war").getAbsolutePath());
task.execute();
```

Thanks to this solution I'm able to develop project that can update automatically my apps.

Comment: Hi, I get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/Task". Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There's a set of tools (well, a .jar) released with Tomcat that's usually used by `ant` but that can be used by anyone willing to call the code. There are tasks for starting and stopping applications, deploying, undeploying, listing applications and so forth; essentially it's an API that wraps the functionality of the `manager` servlet.

One moment while I try to dig up the name or a link for you...

Here's Apache's information on this stuff: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing Manager Commands With Ant

... and here's a user, elsewhere, describing in detail how he uses these tasks: http://raibledesigns.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=TomcatAntTasks

You may object that you're not `ant`. That's true, but there's nothing magic about ant, it's just calling code inside the jar. That code can be called from anywhere else that follows the API.

Here's a tutorial on *writing* ant tasks: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html

Not quite the same, but it should give you an idea of how the API works.

I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to call this API from within a servlet if you want to.

Alternatively, you could run the `manager` servlet in your Tomcat and simply access the manager application like a Web service: Use your browser or WireShark to snoop on the traffic between your browser and Tomcat when you deploy an app, and then duplicate that to remote control `manager`. Me, I think using the tools jar is simpler.

Comment: Thanks to your advices I found a solution. I posted it in another answer.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a "project lifecycle" tool, this undeploy/deploy can be automatized in the development cycle.

Saying that, I think about Maven2 and his "maven-deploy" plugin :

- mvn compile : java compilation
- mvn package : creation of the war file (for a webbapp project)
- mvn deploy : stop, undeploy the old application, deploy and start the new version !

After, you can couple this automatization with a continous integration server (like Hudson).

Comment: You're suggesting running Maven from another app? I think he's talking Web apps here.

Comment: You're right... In that case, the "maven-deploy" source code (which is public) can be a good example of how to implement this functionnality in another application.