# Deploying to Tomcat by ANT

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, ant

I'm trying to deploy WAR like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144674/758661

```
DeployTask task = new DeployTask();
  task.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/manager/text");
  task.setUsername("tomcat");
  task.setPassword("s3cret");
  task.setPath("/updater");
  task.setWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());
  task.execute();
```

But get an 403 error:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: 
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fupdater
```

I think it is because "/" has been replaced to "%2F" (password and username are like in tomcat-users.xml)

How can I prevent replacing "/" to "%2F"? Or any other ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it.

In Overview of Tomcat Server in Eclipse (right-click on server -> open) in "Server Locations" I had to choose the secons radio-button "Use Tomcat installation" (by default it set to first "Use workspace metadata".

Because in default case Tomcat starts without the manager app wich needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement isn't a problem, it's normal for a parameter to be urlencoded. The server wouldn't be able to receive it if it weren't encoded.

And "403" means "forbidden".

I suppose it's because you have a strange URL. Replace

```
task.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/manager/text");
```

by

```
task.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/manager");
```