# Java wrapper class/library for Tomcat manager

Tags: java, wrapper, tomcat8, tomcat-manager

I am wondering if there is a simple wrapper class/library for the Tomcat Manager application. I am writing a script to deploy my war to a remote instance of Tomcat (hosted on AWS).

I know I can directly use HTTP to communicate with the manager script interface, but I thought this would be a common problem, so I do not want to re-invent the wheel. I found a python solution [here](https://github.com/kotfu/tomcat-manager/), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4432684/2600184) talks about using curl, but I can't find a java solution (which is funny, Tomcat is used by Java developers, not bash developers!) Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html

Comment: @KarlNicholas No, this is just the documentation for Tomcat source code. Not an actual API

Comment: Is it bad that one year later, I had the same question and found this post on google? =P

Comment: Stackoverflow is a knowledge repository, so, no, it's not bad. Might mean you're getting old though .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4144674/2600184). I can use the Tomcat Ant library. In order to do so, all I need is the `catalina-ant.jar` from `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` in my project's dependencies.

```
org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask task = new org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask();
task.setUrl("http://localhost:8084/manager");
task.setUsername("managerLogin");
task.setPassword("managerPassword");
task.setPath("/UrlToYourDeploadingProject");
task.setWar(new File("c:/Project.war").getAbsolutePath());
task.execute();
```